# Choosing better query out of 2 queries, both returning same results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008

I am having two different sql queries one written by me and one automatically generated by C# when used with linq, both are giving same results.

### I am not sure which one to choose, Iam looking for

1. Whats the best way to choose one query out of many, when all returns same result (most optimized query).
2. Out of my queries (below written), which one should i choose.

### Hand Written

```
select * from People P
inner join  SubscriptionItemXes S
on
P.Id=S.Person_Id
inner join FoodTagXFoods T1
on T1.FoodTagX_Id = S.Tag2

inner join FoodTagXFoods T2
on T2.FoodTagX_Id = S.Tag1

inner join Foods F
on
F.Id= T1.Food_Id and F.Id= T2.Food_Id

where p.id='1'
```

### Automatically Generated by LINQ

```
SELECT 
[Distinct1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Distinct1].[Item] AS [Item]
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent2].[Item] AS [Item]
    FROM    [dbo].[People] AS [Extent1]
    CROSS JOIN [dbo].[Foods] AS [Extent2]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[FoodTagXFoods] AS [Extent3] 
    ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent3].[Food_Id]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SubscriptionItemXes] AS [Extent4] 
    ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent4].[Person_Id]
    WHERE (N'rusi' = [Extent1].[Name]) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[FoodTagXFoods] AS [Extent5]
        WHERE ([Extent2].[Id] = [Extent5].[Food_Id]) 
            AND ([Extent5].[FoodTagX_Id] = [Extent4].[Tag1])
    )) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[FoodTagXFoods] AS [Extent6]
        WHERE ([Extent2].[Id] = [Extent6].[Food_Id]) 
            AND ([Extent6].[FoodTagX_Id] = [Extent4].[Tag2])
    ))
)  AS [Distinct1]
```

### Execution Plan Results

Hand Written: Query Cost (relative to batch):33%

Linq Generated: Query Cost (relative to batch):67%

Comment: Do they both have the same query plan ?

Comment: That cross join on `Foods` looks worrying. If you remove the `DISTINCT` how many rows does the Linq version return and how many does the non Linq one return?

Comment: WOW. Isn't LINQ supposed to make SQL easier? That is a mouthful and much harder to read than the original.

Comment: As @Adrian suggests you should compare the execution plans for each.

Comment: @Aaron, LINQ makes SQL easier by not exposing you to it.

Comment: @Abe well I'd definitely want to be exposed to this verbose version.

Comment: @Abe this is the exact kind of query I was afraid of when they first started promoting LINQ - I saw all kinds of examples with cross joins, nested subqueries, etc. when a simple join would do. I am sure that sometimes it gets it right but I bet sometimes it gets it really wrong, too.

Comment: @Rusi, can we see the LINQ that is generating this SQL?

Comment: From the queries as described, I wouldn't bother joining against `Foods`, since (presuming that `Food_Id` is a foreign key) you can simply compare `T1.Food_Id = T2.Food_Id`.

Comment: +1 @Abe, we absolutely must see the **C#** that this SQL was generated from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found that two different queries, one hand-written and one generated by Linq might look wildly different but, actually, when you analyse the query plan in SSMS, you find that actually they are almost identical.

You need to actually run these queries in SSMS with `Display Actual Execution Plan` switched on, and analyse the different plans.  It's the only way to correctly analyse the two and find out which is better.

In general, Linq is actually very good at generating efficient queries; even if the actual SQL itself is pretty ugly (in some cases, it's the kind of SQL that a human would write if they had the time!). If course, that said, it can also generate some pigs!

Additionally, asking SO to help with performance of a query over so many tables is fraught with problems for us, since it will be governed so much by your indexes :)

Comment: just ran `Display Actual Execution Plan`: Hand Written Query Cost: 33% relative to Batch and Linq generated Query Cost: 67%. Does this mean hand written is better.

Comment: Yes it does, its about twice as fast

Comment: I have found that SO can be good for these kind of questions if you get people involved use the Socratic method.  It may just end up as in this case that the questioner is given the tools to answer their own question, rather than an answer that can be marked as correct.   Nice answer by the way.

Comment: @Adrian Russell - thanks; and a good point too - SO has so many uses!  Now can it make my next cup of coffee for me...

Answer (score 3):

But they aren't quite returning the same thing... The first query grabs everyting (SELECT *) while LINQ is going to extract what you really want (id and item). Trivial you may say but streaming back lots of data that's never used is a good waste of bandwidth and will make your application appear sluggish.  Additionally, the LINQ query seems to be doing a lot more which may or may not be the correct solution especially as data is populated into FoodTagXFoods

As for which performs better, I couldn't tell you without something like the actual query plans and/or results of statistics io from both queries. My money is on hand-written but maybe because I like my hands.

Comment: Also, what is "the same thing" - same number of rows? There's no `ORDER BY` so unless currently there is a small number of rows, I wonder how solidly this has been verified?

Answer (score 0):

Examining SQL Server Query Execution Plan is the best way to choose the better query.

Hope below tutorials help.

[SQL Tuning Tutorial - Understanding a Database Execution Plan (1)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql-tuning-tutorial-1.aspx)

[Examining Query Execution Plans](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Examining_Query_Execution_Plans)

[SQL Server Query Execution Plan Analysis](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/query-execution-plan-analysis/)

[SQL SERVER – Actual Execution Plan vs. Estimated Execution Plan](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/28/sql-server-actual-execution-plan-vs-estimated-execution-plan/)